# Getting value of member depending on underlying object type

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I have two structs from a third party library so I can't change their layout. But I have two structs I wrote on my own which match their signature so I can add functions to them (again, but not their layout, therefore also no virtual functions). The structs are called `Foo1` and `Foo2`. Both have the same member called `_b`, but at **different** offsets.

```
struct FooBase { };

struct Foo1 : FooBase
{
    int _a = 2;
    int _b = 1;
};

struct Foo2 : FooBase
{
    int _b = 2;
};

struct Wrap
{
    Wrap(const FooBase& x) : _x(x) { }
    FooBase& _x;
    int GetValue() { return /* MISSING */; }
};
```

I have a wrapper class called `Wrap`. I am looking for a way to return the value of `_b` without using virtual functions in the foo classes, since I can't change their size anymore.

```
Foo1 f1 = Foo1();
Wrap x = f1;
int a = x.GetValue(); // should return 1

Foo2 f2 = Foo2();
Wrap y = f2;
int b = y.GetValue(); // should return 2
```

Any ideas? I posted an approach in the comments but curious for a better solution.

Comment: `Foo1::_b` and `Foo2::_b` are totally unrelated. It seems like there should be a way to do this statically, since they have the same name, but that's not how it works. If all `Foo` have a `int _b` data member, then it should be a member of `FooBase` instead.

Comment: I could add a `std::function` to `Wrap` which would contain the function of `Foo1` or `Foo2` which returns the member. I don't feel like that's the best solution though

Comment: Beware [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/10077)! Your `_x` needs to be a reference, not a value. A `FooBase` instance has neither `_a` nor `_b`.

Comment: Yes, they would have the same name but otherwise are unrelated. That's what makes it so difficult to wrap my head around this

Comment: @FredLarson: Indeed, thanks for spotting, fixed

Comment: @HelloWorld Just pretend they have different names. Or even give them different names if it helps.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux: I can't change their structure anymore, these are not my types

Comment: When you construct a `Wrap` instance, do you have a concrete type to give the constructor, or just a `FooBase&`?

Comment: @HelloWorld Then there is nothing you can do with a `FooBase`. You need to capture the concrete type in some way.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux: I updated the first part of my question accordingly to your comment. Thanks a lot! @FredLarson: Wrap could have information, if it is `Foo1` or `Foo2` and the wrap class can also look how I want it too look like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cpp
struct Wrap
{
    Wrap(const Foo1& x) : _b(x._b) { }
    Wrap(const Foo2& x) : _b(x._b) { }
    int& _b;
    int GetValue() { return _b; }
};
```

Unless a class is needed, you can use a function template to the same effect.

```
template <typename Foo> int getValue(Foo const& foo)
{
   return foo._b;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the user has knowledge of the real type of `x`.

Comment: Seems like the return type of GetValue in the original snippet was already influenced by it?

Comment: The return type of `GetValue` is clearly `int` in all cases.

Comment: @RSahu: Nice one!

Comment: I feel so silly now. I focused too much by getting Foo into the Wrap class instead of the actual member as a reference. I accept this as an answer. The int-ref member approach solves my issue. Thanks a lot!